# how do I output the contents of a while read line loop to multiple arrays in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, while-loop

I read the files of a directory and put each file name into an array (SEARCH)
Then I use a loop to go through each file name in the array (SEARCH) and open them up with a while read line loop and read each line into another array (filecount).  My problem is its one huge array with 39 lines (each file has 13 lines) and I need it to be 3 seperate arrays, where 
filecount1[line1] is the first line from the 1st file and so on.  here is my code so far...

```
typeset -A files
for file in ${SEARCH[@]}; do
    while read line; do
        files["$file"]+="$line"
    done < "$file"
done
```

So, Thanks Ivan for this example!  However I'm not sure I follow how this puts it into a seperate array because with this example wouldnt all the arrays still be named "files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 6 is

```
$filecount[$linenum]}="$line"
```

Seems it is missing a `{`, right after the `$`.
Should be:

```
${filecount[$linenum]}="$line"
```

---

If the above is true, then it **is** trying to run the *output as a command*.
Line 6 is (after "fixing" it above):

```
${filecount[$linenum]}="$line"
```

However `${filecount[$linenum]}` is a **value** and you *can't have an assignment on a value*.
Should be:

```
filecount[$linenum]="$line"
```

---

Now I'm confused, as in whether the `{` is actually missing, or `}` is the actual typo :S :P

---

btw, bash supports this syntax too

```
filecount=$((filecount++)) # no need for $ inside ((..)) and use of increment operator ++
```

---

This should work:

```
typeset -A files
for file in ${SEARCH[@]}; do       # foreach file 
    while read line; do            # read each line
        files["$file"]+="$line"    # and place it in a new array
    done < "$file"                 # reading each line from the current file
done
```

a small test shows it works

```
# set up
mkdir -p /tmp/test && cd $_
echo "abc" > a
echo "foo" > b
echo "bar" > c

# read files into arrays
typeset -A files
for file in *; do 
    while read line; do
        files["$file"]+="$line" 
    done < "$file"
done

# print arrays
for file in *; do
    echo ${files["$file"]}
done

# same as:
echo ${files[a]}     # prints: abc
echo ${files[b]}     # prints: foo
echo ${files[c]}     # prints: bar
```

Comment: I think the original `}` was a typo ;) but after your suggestion of `filecount[$linenum]="$line"` it worked!
Any ideas on how to make the linenum array "restart" after so many lines have been "written" to filecount?

Comment: Ok now that I've got the loop working without errors, I'm not sure how to access elements in the filecount array with a specific linenum...?

Comment: @Ryan: linenum is not an array and you are using filecount both in array and non-array contexts.  You should correct your question to the current version of the code, separate out the two uses of filecount, and then clarify what you you mean by "restart" and "so many lines".  However, you are certainly free to undef the array and reset linenum back to 1 to zap the current array contents.

Comment: @Ryan: echo ${filecount[$index]}

Comment: If I understand correctly, Ryan is actually trying to create arrays in a dynamic way. One array per file, where each of those will hold the file's content. This can be done with associative arrays. See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for more.

Comment: @Ryan please see the last part of my (edit-again) answer. It should work, I think.

Comment: That looks/sounds like it might be just what I need.  Not sure if I'll be able to figure it out but you guys have provided some excellent and timely feedback so I might be back here very shortly!  Thanks again for the help/suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to store the file contents into an array:

```
declare -A contents
for file in "${!SEARCH[@]}"; do
    contents["$file"]=$(< $file)
done
```

If you want to store the individual lines in a array, you can create a pseudo-multi-dimensional array:

```
declare -A contents
for file in "${!SEARCH[@]}"; do
    NR=1
    while read -r line; do
        contents["$file,$NR"]=$line
        (( NR++ ))
    done < "$file"
done

for key in "${!contents[@]}"; do 
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${contents["$key"]}"
done
```

Comment: Glenn, your solution works well but it still puts the files contained in `SEARCH[]` into one array, `contents[]`  What I'm looking for is a structure that will take every file in `SEARCH[]`, make an array for that file and then put the contents of that file as elements of the file array.  So if I have 3 files in `SEARCH[]` and each file has 5 lines I want to be able to have 3 arrays with 5 distinct elements each... I believe Ivan said it correctly about "dynamically creating arrays" but I still wasnt able to figure out his example... :S

Comment: If you think you really need to do that, you'll have to jump through a lot of hoops with creating variable names and `eval`. Easy to create an unmaintainable mess that way.

Comment: Yea you may be right, I'm trying to think through my logic to see if I can do what I want a different way.  thank you everyone for your help.